# Django: Why does the text that I placed in Django Summernote displays HTML tags in my HTML template?

Tags: html, django, summernote

I have installed Django Summernote by following the guide from GitHub and have successfully added it to my admin page. However, when I try to edit the text using summernote and view it on the HTML template, it shows the code view instead of the text only. I'm new to Django so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

#### My admin page where summernote is applied:

[image: admin page]

#### My html page where the above would be viewed:

[image: html page]

#### admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin

from .models import Post

class PostAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = ('body',)

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

#### models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    body = models.TextField()

    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

#### EDIT: Where I display the "body" in my HTML template:

```
{% block body %}   

    ...

    <p>{{ post.body }}</p>

    ...

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you show the template of html file if you know where it is?

Comment: okay i have edited my post and added the html file code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe) filter here.

> **Safe**
>   Marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output. When autoescaping is off, this filter has no effect.

Your edit:

`<p>{{ post.body | safe }}</p>`