# How to escape HTML tags in NextJS

Tags: django, next.js, summernote

I have Django backend and Nextjs frontend.

When I try to render
`content = models.TextField()` from my Django backend to Nextjs frontend `<p>{data.content}</p>` , I get following rendered:

```
<p>first&nbsp;first&nbs</p>
```

I use django_summernote as the editor. Django has | [safe method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61819183/django-why-does-the-text-that-i-placed-in-django-summernote-displays-html-tags), that escapes rendering HTML, but I don't know what to use for NextJS. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape html tags in next js and safely render HTML from API with styles in page. So you have to do that add the following code:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.content }}></div>
```